# List IndexError when finding data point satisfied the condition

Tags: python, list, indexing

Two simple lists. I want to check if in list_1, there is nth data point is >= the nth data point in list_2, at the same time the (n-1)th data point in list_1 is <= the (n-1)th data point in list_2, and the (n+1)th data point in list_1 is >= the (n+1)th data point in list_2.

What I came up with is:

```
for num, l1 in enumerate(list_1):
    if list_1[num-1] <= list_2[num-1] and list_1[num] >= list_2[num] and list_1[num+1] >= list_2[num+1]:
        print ("ok")
```

These lines work on:

```
list_1 = [586, 586, 586, 585]
list_2 = [586, 586, 586, 586]
```

But it's "IndexError: list index out of range" when:

```
list_1 = [193, 194, 195, 196]
list_2 = [195, 195, 195, 196]
```

What's the proper way to write it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
for num in range(len(list_1)-1):
    if list_1[num-1] <= list_2[num-1] and list_1[num] >= list_2[num] and list_1[num+1] >= list_2[num+1]:
        print("ok")
```